# oracle xe ftp upload

Tags: oracle, plsql, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file via ftp from a file system, I can connect without issue using the example of this ad http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql.php and I managed to perform the connection but when I upload the file I mark error 550 file not found, I suppose that is why I am putting urls in the program because I am from oracle xe windows.

Does anyone know if I'm putting the url properly? or what am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
DECLARE
    l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN 
    l_conn := ftp.login('IPADDRES', '21', 'USR', 'PWD');
    ftp.binary(l_conn);
    ftp.get(l_conn,
      'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\files\file.pdf',
      'C:\FTP\files',
      'file.pdf');
    ftp.logout(l_conn);
END;
```

Comment: You're trying to retrieve a file from the remote system onto the Oracle server, or send a file from the Oracle server to remote? It looks like the third parameter needs to be an Oracle `DIRECTORY` object name not a file path; not sure that's related to the error though.

Comment: ok, reading a bit I realized that the parameter utl_file_dir is already obsolete, so create two folders with this command:

create or replace directory FILE_ORIGIN as 'C:\OracleXE\app\oracle\files'; 
create or replace directory FILE_DESTINY as 'C:\ftp'; 

grant read, write on directory FILE_ORIGIN to public; 
grant read, write on directory FILE_DESTINY to public; 

so my code is now as follows: 

    l_conn: = ftp.login ('IP', '21 ',' usr ',' pwd '); 
    ftp.binary (l_conn); 
    ftp.get (l_conn, 
    'FILE_ORIGIN/file1.pdf' 
    'FILE_DESTINY' 
    'file2.pdf'); 
    ftp.logout (l_conn);

Comment: if the second parameter is the path where the file is left as the route that has the UTL_FILE_DIR (/OracleXE/app/oracle/files/file.pdf) works perfectly but when I change FILE_ORIGIN not work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The path on the remote server won't be an Oracle `DIRECTORY` object, only the local location. The remote file won't be accessed with `UTL_FILE`; that's just for storing the local file, after it's been transferred. (Sounds like you're maybe connecting back to the same box as a test, which is probably adding to the confusion; Oracle can't have a directory on what is *logically* a different box, even if it happens to actually be the same one).

Comment: This is the orginal code: 
DECLARE
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_conn := ftp.login('ftp.company.com', '21', 'ftpuser', 'ftppassword');
  ftp.binary(p_conn => l_conn);
  ftp.get(p_conn      => l_conn,
          p_from_file => '/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0.1.0/sysman/reporting/gif/jobs.gif',
          p_to_dir    => 'MY_DOCS',
          p_to_file   => 'jobs_get.gif');
  ftp.logout(l_conn);
END; 

Take it from http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql.php

the first parameter (p_from_file) is the url that i had as UTL_FILE_DIR it means /oraclexe/app/oracle/files/ in db

Comment: but as said the documentation, 'MY DOCS' is the remote directory and then it works with FILE_DESTINY as directory, why the first parameter doesnt work at the same way?

Comment: See my last comment. `FILE_ORIGIN` is a directory on your local server, not remote. It's an object to the DB. It isn't just a variable; are you thinking it's expanded in the command like, say, `%FILE_ORIGIN%` in Windows? It's not like that at all.

Comment: i got it, thanks a lot Alex :)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you refer to, the remote directory where you will upload the file must be an Oracle directory.

- create directory on the remote database

```
    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE public DIRECTORY MY_DOCS as 'C:\FTP\files';
```

- then only you will be able to use it as intended:

```
    ftp.get(
      p_conn      => l_conn,
      p_from_file => 'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\files\file.pdf',
      p_to_dir    => 'MY_DOCS',
      p_to_file   => 'file.pdf');
```